# This.routerExtensions.back() to call a method/function

Tags: routes, nativescript

So for my app, I need to be able to do this.router.back (or whatever the correct syntax would be). I did `import {Router} from "@angular/router";` and added `constructor(private router: Router) { }`.  How do I do a navigate.back?

---EDIT---
Now that I have navigated back, how do I get a method/function to run when on the page I navigate back to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";`

`constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions){}`

`this.routerExtensions.back();`

http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation#navigating-back

Comment: thanks but isnt there a way to this this without the nativescript? like im developing a {N} and Angular app but i was hoping to do the routing solely in angular

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, because nativescript has it's own location strategy. read more about it : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/wiki/Router#location-strategy

Comment: Thats fine, thanks for the help though. It really helps my app.